# Sublime, saving .styl sending .css

Tags: javascript, css, stylus

Is there any way the sublime, when saving a file .styl it send to the server the css file? I'm using FTPSync.

Comment: What are you talking about? What kind of server?

Comment: just save the file as a .css

Answer (score 0):

If you want a .css file on the server (and to be accessible from your web page), you will need to save the file in sublime as a .css file.

You can simply rename your .styl file to end with .css

Answer (score 0):

When you save the file make sure you click .css when the window opens up asking how to save the file and in what format.